# create batch file for postgres in japanese os

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I have a batch file (`01_update.bat`) and SQL (`update.sql`) file

**01_update.bat**

```
echo.
pause
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\psql.exe" -U postgres -d javasamplepj_core -f .\update.sql 
pause
```

**update.sql**

```
DELETE FROM "CORE_LANGUAGE_PROPERTY" WHERE "KEY" = 'error_incompletedate';
```

==> but when I run batch file I get this error:

> psql: ./ update.sql: 1: ERROR: the 0xef 0xbb byte sequence in the coding scheme "SJIS" 
>   Character is not equal in the "UTF8" encoding scheme with

Comment: Did you save the SQL file with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)?  I think psql doesn't support that.

Comment: No, Its only UTF-8 without BOM

Comment: Then why did you accept the answer that states exactly that as well?

Comment: i reinstall my OS and its working file. thanks for your replay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling for the 0xef 0xbb byte sequence leads to BOM. In Notepad++ for example you can specify if you want to have it saved with or without BOM. That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for giving answer .